# Replacing numbers with Font Awesome (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Ok please don't give me slack for asking this question, I'm pretty new to jQuery. I'm kind off making my own rating system using Advanced Custom Fields plugin for Wordpress (Because I couldn't find one).

I have an ACF named Ranking in which I fill in a number, like 1. Using a `replace` function I found here on Stackoverflow I replace the `1` with `<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>` (one star from Font Awesome).

This works fine for the first item, in this case it's `2` so I get 2 stars. But the second value is a `5` but it shows `2` stars. It looks like it doesn't see the difference or something. If I remove the replace script it really shows a 2 and a 5.

I've tried several things including the `/1/g` I read some where to use it globally, but that didn't work. Do I need a `foreach` or something to make this work? Of should I abandon this whole idea of replacing values?

Here is my code (this outputs a value from 1 to 5 (No .5's):

```
<?php if( get_field('ranking') ): ?>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-top">Ranking:</td>
        <td class="star_ranking"><?php the_field('ranking'); ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$('.star_ranking').html($('.star_ranking').html().replace(/1/g,'<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>'));
$('.star_ranking').html($('.star_ranking').html().replace(/2/g,'<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>'));
$('.star_ranking').html($('.star_ranking').html().replace(/3/g,'<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>'));
$('.star_ranking').html($('.star_ranking').html().replace(/4/g,'<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>'));
$('.star_ranking').html($('.star_ranking').html().replace(/5/g,'<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>'));
```

I have searched Stackoverflow but I couldn't find a similar question.

Comment: your jquery needs rewriting.. you're targeting an element, replacing the element with itself, except replaces the number with an icon... a for loop would be a better approach here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/9fo1fz77/

```js
$('.star_ranking').each(function() {
 var starCnt = parseInt($(this).html());
  $(this).html('');
  for(var i=0; i<starCnt; i++){
   $(this).append('<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-top">Ranking:</td>
      <td class="star_ranking">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-top">Ranking:</td>
      <td class="star_ranking">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-top">Ranking:</td>
      <td class="star_ranking">5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Excellent! This works! Thank you very much!! I'm a happy camper! (To much exclamation marks?)

Comment: Welcome Jay-oh :)

Answer (score 0):

Shiladitya's answer is the way I'd usually go about it, but you might also consider trying the `repeat()` method:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var faIcon = '<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>';

  jQuery('.star_ranking').each(function(){
    jQuery(this).html(
    faIcon.repeat(
      parseInt( jQuery(this).html() )
    ));
  });

});
```

(You can see it in action at https://jsfiddle.net/travisseitler/phLndwpy/.)

**NOTE:** `repeat()` is part of ECMAScript 6, so it's not as backwards-compatible as Shiladitya's answer. All current browsers support it, though, so YMMV.